# (VB or C#) Run app in system tray and listen to keyboard input even when the app is not in focus

Tags: c#, vb.net, keyboard

I want to make an app which on loading sits in the system tray and even after I open another program (say notepad or vlc or anything) i.e. even when the app is not in focus and if I press <kbd>G</kbd> on my keyboard, the tray icon should show a tool tip - "key G is pressed".
I have tried several codes but nothing works when the app goes out of focus. I can use [`Register Hot Key`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309(VS.85).aspx) but it needs a modifier also (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> etc. along with my key <kbd>G</kbd>). So, is there any way I can achieve this?
something which many tray icons do like antivirus apps, etc.
and I do not want to use `AutoHotkey` application. I want to build one but need some help.

Comment: Building a keylogger are we? ;)

Answer (score 3):

WindowsHookLib.dll have saved me many times. It lets you hook both mouse and keyboard system wide very easy.

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=436321

to hook the keyboard and act when 'G' is pressed:

```
Imports WindowsHookLib
Public Class frmMain

    Dim WithEvents gkh As New LLKeyboardHook

    Private Sub frmMain_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        gkh.RemoveHook()
        ghk.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        gkh.InstallHook()
    End Sub


    Private Sub gkh_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WindowsHookLib.KeyEventArgs) Handles gkh.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.G Then
            REM G is pressed!                
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub gkh_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WindowsHookLib.KeyEventArgs) Handles gkh.KeyUp
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.G Then
            REM G was pressed and now released
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use Keyboard hook. Here are several implementations: [Keyboard hooks](http://www.codeproject.com/info/search.aspx?artkw=keyboard+hook&sbo=kw)

Comment: Hey, I already built my app using Hook yday itself. anyways Thanks for the reply. you can check out my app @ http://bit.ly/CapsLockStatus

Comment: That's nice. It would be good if you marked the reply that helped you as an answer so that others find it useful too.